# What's the purpose of the 'software' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The software tag is currently applied to [36 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software).

As far as I can tell, this tag has little meaning and no usefulness--practically any question could be tagged with it--so I am thinking one of the moderators should delete it from the site.

Am I wrong? What are the arguments for keeping it?

I recommend also reviewing a related discussion at [Tag synonym proposal - software and free related tags](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/tag-synonym-proposal-software-and-free)

Comment: Good question!  Some of those tags are obviously useless, but in other cases they appear to be applied by people looking for special-purpose software.

Comment: I wonder if sometimes people use it when they really mean _off-the-shelf software_.  Maybe we need a COTS tag?

Comment: Maybe "software-request", for someone wanting to get input on which software package to use?

Comment: @til_b I think "software-request" could be confused with "software-enhancement" or "enhancement-request" so perhaps "software-choice" or "software-advice" might be useful for some people but I'm loathe to second guess.  Overall, I'm still thinking we should simply delete "software" as an available tag.

Comment: I think this general tag can be used by those new users who can not create new tags. They might want to tag the question with some specific software tags (maybe not commonly used), but they are just not available. The same goes for tag 'tools', and it has more questions tagged.

Comment: @Mingfeng Rather than use such a generic tag that can be applied to just about any question my recommendation would be to wait and create the rare tag once the [**required reputation**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) has been achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give this proposal an actual answer, I would like to remark that the comment thread to the question contains multiple arguments against it and some suggestions for alternatives, but it appears nobody else has stepped up in support of the proposal.  My interpretation is that the community does not approve the proposal.

Comment: There is a new discussion about the [tag:software] tag at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/tag-synonym-proposal-software-and-free