# Tag synonym proposal - software and free related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Two more closely related tag terms with some duplication and cross-use, some of which I believe should go away. It appears some of this has come up before (see below, linked question). Key: (# questions, Wiki excerpt, Wiki full)

- [software](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) (36, "Attached to questions seeking software to
  perform a specified task.", "Note that there also exists a
  free-software tag to exclude commercial software solutions.")
- [software-advice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-advice) (95, "Requests for
  tools/packages/functionalities without having a software
  preference.", "This tag is ambiguous. Use it together with additional
  tags to fully address the question's content. Reference: [What's the
  purpose of the 'software' tag?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/whats-the-purpose-of-the-software-tag)")
- [free-software](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-software) (35, none, none)
- [free](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) (15, none, none)
- [free-sources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-sources) (24, none, none)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inclusion of tags [free](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free), [free-sources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-sources) and [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) in this Q&A leads me to think:

- [software-recommendations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) as master to [software-advice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-advice) and [software](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) with perhaps some disambiguation of the latter first.  This tag name will match up better with the [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site which we could reference in its tag wiki too.
- [free-software](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-software) as master to [free](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) after disambiguating free data
- [free-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-data) as master to [free-sources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-sources) (easy to create via a merge that leaves the latter behind as a synonym)
- [commercial-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial-data) (new) to try and start distinguishing the two main categories of data that people are seeking here.

Disambiguating [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) as part of this process should help rather than hinder any future decisions by the community to start re-directing some/all [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) questions to [Open Data (Beta) SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com).

---

About disambiguating [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data), refer to follow up discussion on:

[How should data questions be tagged on GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/how-should-data-questions-be-tagged-on-gis-stack-exchange)

Comment: Any chance we can change `software-advice` to `software-recommendations`, to match up better with the [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)? And also to refer to that site in its tag wiki unless it's too niche to have success there.

Comment: @blah238 Sounds like a good idea to me.  Would you like to do a quick (minimal) Q&A to see if we can get consensus?  Mentioning Open Data SE in the data wikis would then make sense too.

Comment: Have to run right now, if someone else wants to give it a go, please do.

Comment: Psh, I'd just edit your answer to propose that change rather than start a whole new Q&A on it. I think it would still be covered under the general umbrella of this question, which I intentionally left open as 'software' *related* tags. I have no objections one way or the other, though that is a rather long tag. I am wondering if data would then be for either/or vs the two specified ones, so all three would still be around.

Comment: @ChrisW Good thinking and done!  It's also a long SE site name :-)  Three data tags would be around initially but over time as people keep asking "do you mean free or commercial?" to [tag:data] tag users I think we will see non-novices start to pre-empt the question by choosing more specific tags.

Comment: Something else that could help is modifying the data wiki to state that one is for either/or, and to please use the others (once they've been created) to specify if you only want one or the other. BTW, please downvote my answer where the free tag stays around, because I can't. :)

Comment: @ChrisW If it starts to challenge then I will :-)

Answer (score 2):

- The tag free goes away, questions edited to be free-software or
  free-sources. Note that free is technically a meta-tag - it cannot stand on its own as a sole tag and must be combined with another.
- The tag software is made synonym to master software-advice.

Answer (score 1):

- The tags free-software and free-sources go away. Questions edited to
  have the free tag, and software-advice or in the case of sources
  [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data). In this case free-sources could be made synonym to data and the free tag added, but this partially a logistics thing. Note that technically free would be a meta-tag, not being able to stand on its own as a sole tag, which are discouraged.
- The tag software is made synonym to master software-advice.